# C# Excel Login Error and Automation

Tags: c#, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have added my script below. I am not sure why I am getting this error. Can anyone guide me what is the reason for this?

```
LoginPageObject objLogin = new LoginPageObject();
XLWorkbook Workbook = new XLWorkbook(@"path");
IXLWorksheet ws = Workbook.Worksheet("Common");
var sltLogin = from a in Workbook.Worksheet(ws) select a;
foreach (var a in sltLogin)
{
    PropertiesCollection.driver.Navigate.GotoURL(a["URL"]);
    objLogin.Login(a["uname"], a["pass"]);
}
```

I am receiving two error message.

> 1. The best overloaded method match for  ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.Worksheet(string)' has some invalid
>      arguments
> 2. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ClosedXML.Excel.IXLWorksheet' to 'string'
> 3. 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver.Navigate()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Is there any solution to get rid of this error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this. This should work. I prefer to use Linq. Hope this will work.

```
LoginPageObject objLogin = new LoginPageObject();
string pathfile = @"source path";
string sheetName = "[sheetname]";
var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathfile);
var abc = from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName)  select a;
foreach (var a in abc)
{
    PropertiesCollection.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(a["URL"]);
}
foreach (var a in abc)
{
    objLogin.Login(a["uname"], a["paswd"]);
}
```